# Define points within a radius for post analysis

Tags: matlab, matrix, distance

I'm new to matlab an I'm trying for figure something out. I have a matrix that is 50x50. It represents data I recorded behind a turbine. The turbine is essentially placed in the center of this plane at the point (25,25). It has a radius of 5. Therefore it reaches to (20,25) to the left and (30,25) to the right of the center of the matrix. I know the formula for distance calculation is `pdist([dpx,dpy;centerx,centery])`. But how do I set this up so that matlab will identify all the points within the radius of 5. Im trying to multiple all these points (only the points within the radius of the turbine) by their distance from the center of the matrix. I imagine a for loop is required but I have no idea how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a coordinate grid:

```
[x, y] = meshgrid(1 : 50);
```

Compute the distance of each grid point from (25, 25):

```
d = sqrt((x - 25) .^ 2 + (y - 25) .^ 2);
```

Generate a logical array that contains 1 (true) for every grid place within the turbine area:

```
turb = (d <= 5);
```

You can plot the result:

```
imagesc(turb)
axis equal tight
```

[image]

Or use `turb` for selecting values from a measurement matrix `m`

```
m(turb)
```

using [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1).

Note that indices (25, 25) do not denote the center of a 50 x 50 grid, but rather (25.5, 25.5).

Comment: That worked. It created a grid with all the points within the radius getting a value of 1 for true. How do I multiply these values by their distance from the center?

Comment: @Jerry, the distances are contained in the array `d`.

Comment: @ A. Donda, should there be a for loop then for the d array. currently my d array only has one value

Comment: @Jerry, no, most of the time you don't need for loops in Matlab. If you enter my code line by line, you will get `d` as a 50 x 50 array.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html

Comment: Sorry that was my error. I have it working now. Thanks for the help. Just one more question. How do I multiple the d matrix by the turb matrix such that I will get a matrix will zeros and just the distances

Comment: @Jerry, that would be `d .* turb`.

Answer (score 1):

Using logical indexing, you can find the relevant indexes in the matrix and select only them:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:50);
centered_valued = ((x-25).^2+(y-25).^2 <= 5^2);
requested_matrix = originalMatrix(centered_values);
```

The `meshgrid` function computes two matrices: the first one contains the *x* indexes in every row, the second one contains the *y* indexes of every column.

You then use boolean computation to find the indexes which are within the radius from the center (located in (25,25).

This logical array then can be used as an "index" for the original matrix. The result will be a smaller matrix (though you might be forced to use the `(:)` operator, as the result is not necessarily a rectangular matrix).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the image processing toolbox, you can also use the `bwdist` command to do the distance calculation for you.

Create a mask with the center point selected:

`bw = zeros(50,50); bw(25,25) = 1;`

Calculate the distance to each point from the center (note `bwdist` also allows for a variety of distance calculations, see `doc bwdist` for details)

`distance = bwdist(bw);`

Create a mask of the turbine pixels:

`turbine = (distance <= 5);`

You asked about multiplying pixels in the turbine by their distance from the center.  If the original data is stored in the 50x50 matrix `orig`, then you can do:

`orig(turbine) = orig(turbine) .* distance(turbine);`